# how does reinterpret_cast works in the following case

Tags: c++, c++11

I am a new to C++ style coding and i am confused with reinterpret_cast and regular c style cast.

code 1:

```
int a=100;
    char *p =reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a);
    cout << *p;
```

gives me out put "d" and i understood it as asci value but the below code

code 2:

```
 char c=10;
    int *p = reinterpret_cast<int *>(&c);
    cout << *p;
```

is giving me some random output.

i thought there will be data loss in code 1 since int is converted to char but it seems like this is happening in code 2. Please help me in understanding this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure about the first one because it's a `char*` but the second one is UB.

Answer (score 0):

You should never use any *_cast before you know more.

```
int a=100;
char *p =reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a);
cout << *p;
```

int is most likely an 32-bit value, represented as 0x64 which read as ASCII is 'd' on some machines and on other the prepended 0's 0x00000064 makes it read like 0x00 (big/little endian).

```
char c=10;
int *p = reinterpret_cast<int *>(&c);
cout << *p;
```

Char is a one byte value, which means the other 3 bytes in the int's representation will be undefined therefore you get garbage.

So you are at least missing how different data types are represented internally, and therefore also how the compiler make the data layout according to the standard.

Comment: Actually the *_cast are all rather safe except reinterpret and const.